# Can't view analytics for short ranges

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities

When I try to view the statistics for my site under mod -> analytics, I can access data if i set the date range to over a week, but if I make a request for a short time span (like from 2011/06/16 to 2011/06/19) then it says "loading data" forever. The data never actually loads.

This started to happen around when you added the "7 days average." It might be linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that was the issue - the 7 day average throws an error.

Starting with the next build the average will only be added for > 7 day selected ranges, so it won't throw an error or appear for these short ranges.